# Merge two LINQ expressions into one

Tags: c#, linq

I have created two LINQ queries to extract same type of value, but basing on different references in database.

```
var productGroupIdList = (from organizationalUnit 
                          in user.OrganizationalUnit
                          from productGroup 
                          in organizationalUnit.ProductGroup
                          select productGroup.ProductGroupId).ToList();
productGroupIdList.AddRange(from subOrganizationalUnit 
                            in user.SubOrganizationalUnit
                            from productGroup 
                            in subOrganizationalUnit.ProductGroup
                            select productGroup.ProductGroupId);
```

Is there any way to connect them into one LINQ query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on all of your answers I made this

```
var productGroupIdList = (from organizationalUnit 
                          in user.OrganizationalUnit
                          from subOrganizationalUnit
                          in user.SubOrganizationalUnit
                          from productGroup 
                          in organizationalUnit.ProductGroup.Concat(subOrganizationalUnit.ProductGroup)
                          select productGroup.ProductGroupId).Distinct().ToList();
```

I have also created this using Lambda

```
user.OrganizationalUnit.SelectMany(x => x.ProductGroup)
    .Concat(user.SubOrganizationalUnit.SelectMany(x => x.ProductGroup))
    .Select(x => x.ProductGroupId)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 4):

As long as they have the exact same structure, you should be able to use `Concat()`, which translates to a `UNION ALL` in SQL.

```
var productGroupIdList = (from organizationalUnit 
                      in user.OrganizationalUnit
                      from productGroup 
                      in organizationalUnit.ProductGroup
                      select productGroup.ProductGroupId)
                   .Concat(
                        from subOrganizationalUnit 
                        in user.SubOrganizationalUnit
                        from productGroup 
                        in subOrganizationalUnit.ProductGroup
                        select productGroup.ProductGroupId)
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: No way to do this with one query?

Comment: @MarekCzaplicki: Technically, this _is_ one LINQ query--`Concat()` is part of LINQ. There are probably more concise ways to accomplish the same thing: for example, you could start with `context.ProductGroups` and query the ones where any `OrganizationalUnit`s or `SubOrganizationalUnit`s have the appropriate user associated with them.

Answer (score 1):

how about you Concat only a part of both queries: the first part, since the 2nd parts are identical?

```
var productGroupIdList = from productGroup in 
            (from organizationalUnit in user.OrganizationalUnit
            select organizationalUnit.ProductGroup)
            .Concat(
                from subOrganizationalUnit 
                in user.SubOrganizationalUnit
                select subOrganizationalUnit.ProductGroup)
        select productGroup.ProductGroupId;
```

or see expanded example where combinedProductGroups are a separate variable (that's 1st part of your query combined for both lists)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var user = new User();

        var combinedProductGroups = (from organizationalUnit
                in user.OrganizationalUnit
                select organizationalUnit.ProductGroup)
            .Concat(from subOrganizationalUnit
                in user.SubOrganizationalUnit
                select subOrganizationalUnit.ProductGroup);

        var productGroupIdList = from productGroup in combinedProductGroups
                select productGroup.ProductGroupId;

    }
}

public class User
{
    public List<OrgUnit> OrganizationalUnit;
    public List<SubOrgUnit> SubOrganizationalUnit;
}

public class OrgUnit
{
    public ProdGroup ProductGroup;
}

public class SubOrgUnit
{
    public ProdGroup ProductGroup;
}

public class ProdGroup
{
    public string ProductGroupId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the tables have the same structure, I am guessing you might be able to

```
var result = user.OrganizationalUnit.SelectMany(x => x.ProductGroup.ProductGroupId)
  .Concat(user.SubOrganizationalUnit.SelectMany(x => x.ProductGroup.ProductGroupId)).ToList();
```

Comment: You can't concat suo and uiszczeniem, but you couls concat UO.pg and suo.pg :)

Comment: @MarekCzaplicki I am pretty much guessing as I don't have any experience with LINQ to SQL, but maybe the updated version is more likely to work. It is still 2 queries, but kind of looks like one :] and should translate into one SQL query like the other answers

Comment: Sorry for previous comment with mistakes, but your previous anwser was pretty close to what I was looking for. I have posted a new answer. Take a look